# JQuery Rotating Banner Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am looking for a JQuery solution to something like the rotating banner located at http://www.bazaarvoice.com.

One where it has a timed scroll but also allows the user to toggle by rolling over tabs. Anyone know of a good, easy to style one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [Cycle Lite](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/lite/) plugin for jQuery.
It's got a vert small footprint and all the features you need:

- Auto scroll
- Pause on hover
- Infinite loop or defined number of loops
- [Use thumbshots as pager elements](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pager2.html)
- [You'll have to use divs instead of images](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/int2.html).

[See more advanced demos right here](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/more.html?v2.23).

*Edit: here's a sample code for you:*
You'll need the [Cycle plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/download.html), not the Cycle Lite plugin.
HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <ul class="pager">
        <!-- will be populated with thumbs by JS -->
    </ul>
    <!-- each div is considered as a slide show -->
    <div><img src="/images/banner1.png" />You can place text here too !</div>
    <div><img src="/images/banner2.png" /></div>
    <div><img src="/images/banner3.png" /></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumb.selected {
    border: 2px gray solid;
}

ul.pager li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

#slideshow > div {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("#slideshow").cycle({ 
    fx:           'fade',  // name of transition effect (or comma separated names, ex: fade,scrollUp,shuffle) 
    timeout:       1000,   // milliseconds between slide transitions (0 to disable auto advance) 
    speed:         400,    // speed of the transition (any valid fx speed value) 
    pager:         "#tabs",// selector for element to use as pager container 
    pagerClick:    null,  // callback fn for pager clicks:  function(zeroBasedSlideIndex, slideElement) 
    pagerEvent:   'hover',// name of event which drives the pager navigation 
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(i, slide){// callback fn for building anchor links:  function(index, DOMelement) 
        return '<li class="thumb" id="thumb-1"><img src="' + slide.src + '" height="30" width="40" /></a></li>';
    },
    before: function(){ // deselect all slides
        $(".thumb").removeClass('selected');
    },
    after: function(foo, bar, opts){ // select current slide
        $("#thumb-"+opts.currSlide).addClass('selected');
    }, 
    fit:           1,     // force slides to fit container 
    pause:         1,     // true to enable "pause on hover" 
    pauseOnPagerHover: 1, // stop slideshow when pagers are being hovered
    autostop:      0,     // true to end slideshow after X transitions (where X == slide count) 
    autostopCount: 0,     // number of transitions (optionally used with autostop to define X)  
    slideExpr:     "div", // all content of div#slider is a slide. but not the pager
    fastOnEvent:   100,   // force fast transitions when triggered manually (via pager or prev/next); value == time in ms 
});
```

Enjoy, it's untested, but should work.

*Edit2:*
Replace the pagerAnchorBuilder option with `return '<li class="thumb" id="thumb-1"><img src="' + slide.src + '" /></a></li>';`

I guess you want to change the width and/or the height. Juste remove the HTML height, and use a CSS property : `.thumb img { height: 10px; width: 10px; }`
You can also add some custom CSS properties.

Comment: I think I need a dumbed down version of this. I am not good enough to know how to do it without a tutorial yet.

Comment: Ok, I added some sample code to help you. You'll have to finish it, and to add some sexy CSS.
Tell me if it doesn't work.

Comment: Wow, you are freaking awesome man. Thanks so much. I am going to implement this later today and will let you know. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: There is all kinds of files in the download. Is there any problem with just using the jquery.cycle.all.min.js?

Comment: I'm having trouble building the anchors. I think I do this in the .js file but not exactly sure how and where.

Comment: What do you call "the anchors" ?

Comment: The little text or image links that the person hovers over and causes it to pause.

Comment: They are being constructed with the pagerAnchorBuilder option:  

See my 2nd edit to give this custom CSS.