# Jquery custom slider infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I did jquery slider using this tutorial

> http://css-plus.com/2010/09/create-your-own-jquery-image-slider/

, where the pictures are sliding automatically, but just once. How can I make them circle in an infinite loop?

on-line example :

> www.vytvarkajablonec.jecool.net/ati

I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: Use setInterval(), and call the function repeatedly
Refer this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: Confer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060140/jquery-rotating-banner-question/2060490#2060490

Answer (score 0):

Just animate the gallary back to it's initial position if it is at the end of the gallary.

```
var oGallary = $('#gallery');
var gallarWidth = oGallary.width();

if(oGalary.position().left > stopPosition && oGallary.is(":animated") == false)
{
    oGallary.animate({left : "-=" + imageWidth + "px"});
}
else if ( oGalary.position().left <= stopPosition && oGallary.is(":animated") == false )
{  
    oGallary.animate({left : "+=" + gallaryWidht + "px"}) // Get full length of the entire gallary
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the JS code from tutorial for this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Gallery
    if (jQuery("#gallery").length) {

        // Declare variables
        var totalImages = jQuery("#gallery > li").length,
            imageWidth = jQuery("#gallery > li:first").outerWidth(true),
            totalWidth = imageWidth * totalImages,
            visibleImages = Math.round(jQuery("#gallery-wrap").width() / imageWidth),
            visibleWidth = visibleImages * imageWidth,
            stopPosition = (visibleWidth - totalWidth);

        jQuery("#gallery").width(totalWidth);

        jQuery("#gallery-prev").click(function () {
            if (jQuery("#gallery").position().left < 0 && !jQuery("#gallery").is(":animated")) {
                jQuery("#gallery").animate({
                    left: "+=" + imageWidth + "px"
                });
            }

            if (jQuery("#gallery").position().left === 0) {
                jQuery("#gallery > li:last").prependTo($("#gallery"));
            }

            return false;
        });

        jQuery("#gallery-next").click(function () {
            if (jQuery("#gallery").position().left > stopPosition && !jQuery("#gallery").is(":animated")) {
                jQuery("#gallery").animate({
                    left: "-=" + imageWidth + "px"
                });
            }

            if (jQuery("#gallery").position().left === stopPosition) {
                jQuery("#gallery > li:first").appendTo($("#gallery"));
            }

            return false;
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Now its stucked at last slide (Here : http://www.vytvarkajablonec.jecool.net/ati/). I meant to When the last slide is arriving, the next one should become the first one. (Slide 1 -> Slide 2 -> Slide 3 -> Slide 1 -> Slide 2 etc....)

Comment: Why are you appending the items again? this will just cause the page to use more memory. AS show in my answer, you may as well "make them circle in an infinite loop" by restarting it at the end, yeah?

Comment: @JiříOláh You change all the code from tutorial? Look to my example http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/NWntU/

Comment: @Sbml I did : http://jsfiddle.net/ChxDr/ . Only my css is bit different, cause i have in it my margin etc...

Comment: Sincerely I don't know why you are using the code from this tutorial when you have so many better options like this for example http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/